# how to convert list of tuples to tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have list like:

```
L = [('a',1),('b',2),....]
```

I want to pass this tuples to the query for bulk insertion.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO [plma].["+tablename+"] VALUES {}".format(L)
```

but this qry takes L as `[(),()]` ,
where to execute this qry properly it needs to be only `(),()`

so I want only tuples from that list L, How to pass them ?

Comment: @TaraPrasadGurung I need it for bulk insert, so no need for iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stringify and strip:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO [plma].["+tablename+"] VALUES " + str(L).strip('[]')
```

Comment: Good answer. I came up with a less elegant way: `sql = "INSERT INTO [plma].["+tablename+"] VALUES {}".format(str(L)[1:-1]`

Answer (score 0):

To join the elements of a list to a string, I would use `.join()` and list comprehension, as I find it rather nice and pythonic:

```
values = ', '.join(str(e) for e in L)
sql = "INSERT INTO [plma].[{}] VALUES {}".format(tablename, values)
```

However, as has been pointed out, there may be better ways to approach the actual issue of inserting into a database.